# If $\mathbf{Y \mid \theta} \sim \mathcal{N}_k (\mathbf{\theta}, A_1)$ & $\mathbf{\theta} \sim \mathcal{N}_k (\mathbf{\mu}, A_2)$, is the joint normal?

Tags: probability, statistics

If we have that $\mathbf{Y \mid \theta} \sim \mathcal{N}_k \left(\mathbf{\theta}, A_1\right)$ and that $\mathbf{\theta} \sim \mathcal{N}_k \left(\mathbf{\mu}, A_2\right)$, where both of these are multivariate normal distributions of dimension $k$, how can I prove that the joint distribution is normal as well?

Comment: Just a guess. There might be some conditional expectation involved http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581229/finding-the-moment-generating-function-of-the-product-of-two-standard-normal-dis

Comment: Hint: Let $V = Y - \Theta$, and $Z = \begin{pmatrix}V  \\ \Theta\end{pmatrix}$. Note that $V|\Theta \sim \mathcal{N}(0, A_1)$. Establish that $Z$ is a jointly gaussian RV using the chain rule. Now use the fact that $\begin{pmatrix}Y \\ \Theta\end{pmatrix}$ is a linear transformation of $\begin{pmatrix}V  \\ \Theta\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 How exactly do you establish that $Z$ is gaussian using the chain rule? Do you mean a jacobian here is used?

Comment: Added an answer, take a look and ask me if you don't understand something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V=Y−\Theta$, and $Z=\begin{pmatrix} V \\ Θ\end{pmatrix}$. Note that $V|Θ \sim \mathcal{N}(0,A_1)$

\begin{align}P_{V\Theta}(v,\theta)  &= P_{V|\Theta}(v|\theta)P_\Theta(\theta)\\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n|A_1|}} \exp\left(\frac{1}{2} v^TA_1^{-1}v\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n|A_2|}} \exp\left(\frac{1}{2} (\theta - \mu)^TA_2^{-1}(\theta-\mu)\right) \\ \implies P_Z(z) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{2n} |B|}} \exp\left(\frac{1}{2} (z-\hat{\mu})^TB^{-1}(z-\hat{\mu})\right)\end{align}
with $\hat{\mu} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \mu\end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} A_1 & 0 \\ 0 & A_2 \end{pmatrix}$

Thus, $Z$ is a gaussian random vector. Finally, $\begin{pmatrix} Y \\ Θ\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}Z$.