# Finding the M.G.F of product of two random variables.

Tags: moment-generating-functions

We are given two independent standard normal random variables $X$ and $Y$. We need to find out the M.G.F of $XY$.

I tried as follows :
\begin{align}
M_{XY}(t)&=E\left(e^{(XY)t}\right)\\&=\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}e^{(XY)t}f_X(x)f_y(y)dxdy \\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}e^{(xy)t}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dxdy \\ &=
\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}e^{-\dfrac{(x-ty)^2}{2}}e^{\dfrac{-t^2y^2}{2}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dxdy \\ &=
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}e^{\dfrac{-t^2y^2}{2}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy \\ &=
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^{2}(\frac{1}{2}+t^2)}dy \\ &=
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+2t^2}}
\end{align}
Is this correct ?

Comment: Small typos in second equality: Exponent should have $(xy)t$ (not uppercase) whereas both subscripts of the PDFs should be capitalized.

Comment: @Semiclassical I'll keep that in mind for next time. Thanks :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/581229/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careless mistake at second last line:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}e^{\dfrac{-t^2y^2}{2}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy &= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}e^{\dfrac{-(t^2+1)y^2}{2}}dy\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}
\end{align}

Edit:

There is actually a mistake earlier. Thanks, tmrlvi for pointing out.

In the $4^{th}$ line as we complete the square:
\begin{align}
&
\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}e^{-\dfrac{(x-ty)^2}{2}}e^{\dfrac{t^2y^2}{2}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dxdy \\ &=
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}e^{\dfrac{t^2y^2}{2}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy \\ &=
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{y^{2}(1-t^2)}2}dy \\ &=
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
\end{align}

Comment: There is additional mistake in the calculation. Final result should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}}$. Convergence radius is $t^2 < 1$. Easier way to arrive the same conclusion is here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51699/moment-generating-function-of-the-inner-product-of-two-gaussian-random-vectors

Comment: @tmrlvi Thanks for pointing out the mistake. The alternative method is cool.

Comment: Funny enough, the solution is $f(t)=1/\sqrt{(1-t^2)}=\arcsin'(t)$. I wonder whether this can be related to angles somehow.