# Moment-generating function of $Z:=X_1X_2+X_3X_4$

Tags: proof-verification, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ be four indipendent random variable with normal distribution of mean 0 and variance 1. The exercise asks me to calculate the moment-generating function of $X_1X_2$. I was able to do it and I found that $$M_{X_1X_2}(z) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$
I believe that this result is correct since I found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026175/finding-the-m-g-f-of-product-of-two-random-variables). The exercise goes on and ask to prove that the moment-generating function of $Z:=X_1X_2+X_3X_4$ is $$M_Z(t)= \displaystyle\frac{1}{1+t^2}$$
What I write was:
$$M_Z(t)=\Bbb E[e^{tZ}]=\Bbb E[e^{tX_1X_2+tX_3X_4}]=\Bbb E[e^{tX_1X_2}e^{tX_3X_4}] \overset{indip.}{=} \Bbb E[e^{tX_1X_2}]\Bbb E[e^{tX_3X_4}]=\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\right)^2=\frac{1}{1-t^2}$$
Am I missing something or there is an error in the exercise's text?

Comment: Result is certainly true : https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/71126/119261.

Comment: Thank you @StubbornAtom. I wasn't able to find a reference of this

Comment: @StubbornAtom I have look that answer but it seems that they are calculating the characteristic function instead of the moment-generating function. In fact $M_Z(t)=\phi(-it)$ (where $\phi$ is the characteristic function) seems to confirm that my calculation where good(I have manually found $M_Z(t)$).

Comment: You are right, sorry. Yes the stated answer is wrong (if it was characteristic function it would have been true). It should be $M_Z(t)=1/(1-t^2)$, as confirmed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution).

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you for your time. If you want to make your comments into an answer I will gladly accept it!

Comment: I would ask you to post an answer and accept it.