# Doubt in product of MGF(moment generating functions) of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

We are given two independent standard normal random variables X and Y. We need to find out the M.G.F of XY.

Let $u=XY$

$M_{XY}(t)=M_{u}(t)=E(e^{xyt}) =E(e^{ut})=  \int_{u=-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ut} f_u(u) du, u =xy $

Now how to split $f_{xy}(xy)$

I saw the solution in [Finding the M.G.F of product of two random variables.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026175/finding-the-m-g-f-of-product-of-two-random-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1)

i recently started probability and statistics. I did not understand how $f_{XY}(XY)$ is split (here it is actually not joint distribution of 2 random variables right? it is pdf of single random variable XY). Kindly elaborate

Comment: The question is answered in great detail in the post that you linked...

Comment: sir i recently started probability and statistics. I am still learning. I did not understand how $f_{XY}(XY)$ is split (here it is actually not joint distribution of 2 random variables right? it is pdf of single random variable XY)

Comment: Perhaps this post is more helpful? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51699/moment-generating-function-of-the-inner-product-of-two-gaussian-random-vectors

Comment: i have not reached till chi square variate

Comment: You might use the composition: $$f_{XY}(u) = \int_\Bbb R (f_X(x)\,f_Y(u/x)/\lvert x\rvert)~\mathrm d x$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't switch between cases.  Mathematics' symbols are case sensitive.

Further, it is preferred standard to use upper-case for random variables, and lower-case for scalar terms (constants, parameters, et cetera).

Now, by the definition, a moment generating function of random variable $U$ with parameter $t$ is the expectation of random variable $\mathrm e^{tU}$: $$\mathsf M_U(t)=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{tU})$$

When $U$ is defined as the product of random variables $X$ and $Y$, we therefore have: $$\mathsf M_{XY}(t)=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{tXY})$$

By the Law of Total Expectation, and the fact that the random variables are independent.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf M_{XY}(t)&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{(tX)Y}\mid X))\\&=(2\pi)^{-1}\int_\Bbb R \mathrm e^{-x^2/2}\int_\Bbb R \mathrm e^{-y^2/2}\cdot\mathrm e^{txy}~\mathrm d y~\mathrm d x\\&=\sqrt{2\pi~}^{-1}\int_\Bbb R \mathrm e^{-x^2/2}\cdot \mathrm e^{t^2x^2/2}~\mathrm d x\\&=\sqrt{2\pi~}^{-1}\int_\Bbb R\mathrm e^{-(1-t^2)x^2/2}~\mathrm d x\\&=\sqrt{1-t^2~~}^{-1}\quad\big[\Re(t^2)<1\big]  \end{align}$$

---

Taking that a few smaller steps at a time.

$$\mathsf M_{XY}(t)=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{(tX)Y}\mid X))\\=\mathsf E(\mathsf M_Y(tX))$$

Now, $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1^2)$ (standard normal), so $\mathsf M_Y(s)=\mathrm e^{s^2/2}$. If you do not already have that available$$\begin{align}\mathsf M_Y(s)&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{sY})\\&=\int_\Bbb R\mathrm e^{sy}\cdot\sqrt{2\pi~}^{-1}\mathrm e^{-y^2/2}\mathrm d y\\&=\sqrt{2\pi}^{-1}\int_\Bbb R\mathrm e^{sy-y^2/2}\mathrm d y\\&=\mathrm e^{s^2/2}\end{align}$$

... Okay. Anyway, using that:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf M_{XY}(t)&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{(tX)^2/2})\\&=\int_\Bbb R\mathrm e^{t^2x^2/2}\cdot\sqrt{ 2\pi~}^{-1}~\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}~\mathrm d x\\&=\sqrt{ 2\pi~}^{-1}\int_\Bbb R\mathrm e^{-(1-t^2)x^2/2}\mathrm d x\\&=\sqrt{1-t^2~}^{-1}\quad\big[\Re(t^2)<1\big]\end{align}$$

Comment: ssir pls keep this for 1 or 2 days. I have yet to do conditional expectation. I am going thru those harvard lectures. I will come back to this once i do conditional expectation. THank you for patiently answering this.