# Distribution of a product of normal distributions : why am I wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent normal distributions with mean $0$ and variance $1$ for simplicity.

I want to find the distribution of $XY$.

Attempt :

$P(XY=w)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}P(X=s)P(Y=\frac{w}{s})ds=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac12s^2-\frac12w^2/s^2}ds$

Using $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ax^2-b/x^2}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}$ (Glasser's theorem or variable change)

with $a=\frac12$ and $b=\frac 12w^2$

I obtain :

$P(XY=w)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-|w|}$

but integrating over $w$ yields $\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\approx0.8<1$

So, which cases am I missing ? Is it because $s=0$ is included and it is illicit ? Even then, I would expect to get something strictly superior to one and not inferior since the integrand is always positive... unless I am missing special cases ?

I know I can find the distribution of $XY$ by a google search, but I'd still like to know where I am making a mistake, so that it doesn't happen again. Sorry if this is trivial, sometimes I just can't see it.

Comment: Does it make sense to have  probability strictly greater than 1?

Comment: $P(XY=w)=0$ -- so, I don't understand this argumentation.

Comment: @n.o. No it doesn't, I was ideally expecting $1$ upon integration, but if I were to do something illicit by adding a special case where I divide by $0$ and it happens not to vanish for whatever reasons, then I would have expected my mistake to bring to the table something strictly superior to $1$. I don't see how I can get something inferior to $1$ without missing cases, which I don't think I did...

Comment: @zoli Right... I think I got it now, thanks...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581229/finding-the-moment-generating-function-of-the-product-of-two-standard-normal-dis/ is relevant if you want to find the MGF of this distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your notation is confused.   You should not use a probability *mass* function when you mean a probability *density* function.

Secondly, the convolution is based on the chain rule of differentiation and the law of total probability.

$$\begin{align}f_{XY}(w) ~&=~ \int_\Bbb R \underset{\text{Jacobian Determinant}}{\underbrace{\left\lVert\frac{\partial(s,w/s)}{\partial (s,w)}\right\rVert} f_X(s)}f_Y(w/s)\operatorname d s \\[1ex] &=~ \frac 1{2\pi} \int_\Bbb R\lvert s^{-1}\rvert \exp(-s^2/2)\exp(-w^2/2s^2)\operatorname d s \\[1ex] &=~\frac 1\pi \int_0^\infty s^{-1}\,\mathsf e^{-(s^2+w^2/s^2)/2}\operatorname d s\end{align}$$

Thirdly, that's not going to resolve into elementary functions.

(Hint Topic: Modified Bessel Function of the Second Kind.)

Comment: An exponent -1 is probably missing in the last expression, but thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've redone the calculations an elementary way, which, in my opinion is better for beginners. (It is lengthier though.)

The pdf of $XY$ can be interpreted the following way

$$f_{XY}(w)=\lim_{\Delta w\to 0}\frac{F_{XY}(w+\Delta w)-F_{XY}(w)}{\Delta w}=\lim_{\Delta w\to 0}\frac{P(w\le XY<w+\Delta w)}{\Delta w}.$$

Let's deal with the probability in the numerator

$$P(w\le XY<w+\Delta w)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(w\le XY<w+\Delta w\mid X=x)e^{-\frac{x^2}2} \ dx=$$
$$=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P\left(w\le xY<w+\Delta w \right)e^{-\frac{x^2}2} \ dx.$$

So,

$$\lim_{\Delta w\to 0}\frac{P(w\le xY<w+\Delta w)}{\Delta w}=$$
$$=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lim_{\Delta w\to 0}\frac{P\left(w\le xY<w+\Delta w\right)}{\Delta w}e^{-\frac{x^2}2} \ dx.\tag 1$$

Now, if $x>0$

$$\lim_{\Delta w\to 0}\frac{P\left(\frac wx\le Y<\frac wx+\frac {\Delta w}x\right)}{\Delta w}=\lim_{\Delta w\to 0}\frac{F_Y\left(\frac wx+\frac{\Delta w}x\right)-F_Y\left(\frac wx\right)}{\Delta w}=$$
$$=\frac{d F_Y\left(\frac wx\right)}{dw}=\frac1xf_Y\left(\frac wx\right)=\frac1{\mid x \mid}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(\frac wx)^2\frac12}$$
If $x<0$
$$\lim_{\Delta w\to 0}\frac{P\left(\frac wx\ge Y>\frac wx+\frac {\Delta w}x\right)}{\Delta w}=\lim_{\Delta w\to 0}\frac{F_Y\left(\frac wx\right)-F_Y\left(\frac wx+\frac {\Delta w}x\right)}{\Delta w}=$$
$$=-\lim_{\Delta w\to 0}\frac{F_Y\left(\frac wx+\frac {\Delta w}x\right)-F_Y\left(\frac wx\right)}{\Delta w}=$$
$$=\frac1{\mid x \mid }f_Y\left(\frac wx\right)=\frac1{\mid x\mid}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(\frac wx)^2\frac12}$$

The case $x=0$ can be considered as if it was omitted from the domain of the integral $(1)$ which looks like this now

$$f_{XY}(w)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac12\left((\frac wx)^2+{x^2}\right)}}{\mid x \mid } \ dx=\frac1{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\ \frac{e^{-\frac12\left((\frac wx)^2+{x^2}\right)}}{x}dx.$$