# Find characteristic function of ZX+(1-Z)Y with X uniform, Y Poisson and Z Bernoulli

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, characteristic-functions

Let random variables $X, Y, Z$ independent. $X$ with uniform distribution on $[-a,a]$, $Y$ with Poisson distribution with parameter $ν$, $Z$ with Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$.

Find the characteristic function of random variable $Z*X+(1-Z)Y$

I tried use the [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016804/characteristic-function-of-a-product-of-random-variables) idea, but i don't now, how i can apply it for discrete distribution.

Why are they independent?(random variables)

No, i can't understand the conversion to replacement Z by p and (1-p). Why we can do it?It is not the meaning of characteristic function.

Comment: Hint: some integrals will become sums, when computing the expectation.

Comment: @ClementC. Not sure this helps.

Comment: "Why are they independent?" What? Who is independent?

Comment: "Why are they independent?(random variables)" Which random variables are independent according to you? (Bis repetita.)

Answer (score 7):

$$T=ZX+(1-Z)Y\implies E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm itT})=pE(\mathrm e^{\mathrm itX})+(1-p)E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm itY})$$