# Characteristic function of product of two random independent variables

Tags: probability-theory, independence, characteristic-functions

I have read [Characteristic function of product of normal random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74013/characteristic-function-of-product-of-normal-random-variables) But I really don't understand the derivation.
Let X and Y be two independent random variables where X ~ N(0,1) and Y~exp(1) Form a new random variable Z = X*Y^(1/2) determine the characteristic function for Z and use this to determine 
$$
f_Z(z)
$$

So starting by doing 
$$
\phi_{Z}(t) = E[e^{itz}] = E[e^{itX\sqrt{Y}}] = E[E[e^{itX\sqrt Y}|Y]]  
$$
After this I am lost. Why is this the same as 
$$
E[\phi_{X}(t\sqrt(y))] ?
$$

Comment: Actually, the correct statement is that $$E[e^{itX\sqrt Y}|Y]=\phi_{X}(t\sqrt{Y})$$ and this holds because, for every $x$, $$E[e^{ixX}]=\phi_{X}(x)$$ and because $(X,Y)$ is independent.

Comment: Could you please show a detailed calculation? Because I really don't get it.

Comment: I am afraid you will have to be *much more specific* (rather than posting duplicates on the site) before I can help you. What is it you do not get? What is $E(e^{itX\sqrt{Y}}\mid Y)$ according to you?

Comment: According to me $E[e^{itX\sqrt(Y)}|Y]$ is the expected value of some function g =g(x,y).

Comment: No. Please check a rigorous definition of the conditional expectation of a random variable conditionally on (the sigma-algebra generated by) another random variable.

Comment: When you say rigorous do you mean more rigorous than the one given by e.g. Gut? $$  E[Y|X=x] = \Sigma_y y*p_{Y|X=x (y)} $$  ?

Comment: Would you mean the formula $$E(Y\mid X=x)=\sum_yyp_{Y\mid X=x}(y)$$ by any chance? Which is not a definition of $E(X\mid Y)$, as you surely noted, and which assumes that $Y$ is discrete (not your case), and which requires to be able to identify $p_{Y\mid X=x}$ for every $x$... The last point in particular is odd since the object $p_{Y\mid X=x}$ is in general more involved than $E(Y\mid X)$.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. So I will cease this thread.

Comment: Not asking anything, simply suggesting that you "check a rigorous definition of the conditional expectation of a random variable conditionally on (the sigma-algebra generated by) another random variable."